# Dockerfile: how download a file using wget with url from a variable

Tags: variables, url, download, dockerfile, wget

I have a Dockerfile with something like that

```
RUN url=$(curl -sL https://... | jq) #simply put url=https://example.com/tar.tgz
RUN wget $url #will fail here
```

The problem IMO is that `RUN` means `/bin/sh -c wget $URL` and wget will complain missing URL
I was trying to outsmart tested locally from terminal `/bin/sh -c "wget -v $url"` and it works, but when put into Docker file as

`RUN "wget -v $url"` then the error is
`ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c \"wget $url\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127` because RUN will escape `"` for you.

Is it possible to download something in Dockerfile using url in a variable or ARG?

Answer (score 0):

The minute after I posted I've found an answer.

Seems like each `RUN` is separate context so just needed to combine commands into single `RUN` like

`RUN url=$(curl -sL https://... | jq) && wget $url`